# Potential mistake in a textbook problem concerning the limit of a function defined by a contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Here is the problem in question:

> When $\Gamma$ is a simple closed contour, the function $G$ defined by
>   $$G(z) := \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma} \frac{g(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}d\zeta$$ is analytic in the domain enclosed by $\Gamma$ (assuming only
>   that $g$ is continuous on $\Gamma$). Show that the limiting values of
>   $G(z)$ as $z$ approaches $\Gamma$ need not coincide with the values of
>   $g,$ by considering the situation where $\Gamma$ is the positively
>   oriented circle $|z|=1$ and $g(z) = 1/z.$

We have $\frac{1}{\zeta(\zeta-z)} = \frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{1}{\zeta-z} - \frac{1}{\zeta}\right),$ whereupon $G(z) = \frac{1/z}{2\pi i}(I_1 - I_2)$ where $$I_1 = \int_{\Gamma} \frac{1}{\zeta - z}d\zeta, \, \, \, \, \, I_2 = \int_{\Gamma} \frac{1}{\zeta}d\zeta.$$

Clearly, $I_2 = 2\pi i$ irrespective of $z$ while $I_1 = 2\pi i$ due to the enclosed singularity. How are we supposed to obtain meaningful information by taking a limit as $z \to \Gamma$, when $G(z) = \frac{1/z}{2\pi i}(2\pi i - 2\pi i) = 0$ before the limit operator is even applied? Also, why does $G$ just vanish? We should at least get $G(z) = 1/z$ if the counterexample is to be properly criticized, so there seems to be a mistake in my reasoning one way or another.

Comment: This is a bit problematic. As near as I can tell, you are right; the integral is zero. We can [explicitly ask Wolfram Alpha about this to be sure.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+2pi+of+1%2F(e%5E(i*theta)(e%5E(i*theta)+-+z))+dtheta) Note we would *not* generally expect $g$ to be related to $G$ since $g$ is not holomorphic in the interior of the unit disk (so the Cauchy Integral Formula does not apply). From where is this problem?

My best guess is that the author is trying to express that knowing the values of something continuous on the boundary is insufficient:

Comment: To quote Wikipedia, *"Note that not every continuous function on the boundary can be used to produce a function inside the boundary that fits the given boundary function. For instance, if we put the function, defined for $|z| = 1, f(z) = 1/z$ into the Cauchy integral formula, we get zero for all points inside the circle. In fact, giving just the real part on the boundary of a holomorphic function is enough to determine the function \[up to\] an imaginary constant — there is only one imaginary part on the boundary that corresponds to the given real part, up to addition of a constant."*